# Como llenar un objeto con propiedades tipo array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola tengo un componente en React que tiene un state tipo objeto: items: {} y mi objetivo es llenarlo con propiedades tipo arreglo. Ejemplo si ingreso en un input un valor Gato se cree : items:{ Gato[] } y si luego ingreso otro valor se cree items: {Gato[], Perro[],...etc}. En la variable s me esta llegando el valor del input y el array Lists se esta llenando correctamente, el problema es con el objeto items. Por favor alguien que me ayude

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Lists from './Lists.js';
import AddList from './AddList.js';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

 constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
lists: [], // this holds the name of each list
items: {} // this property names of this object are the names of the lists; 
their values are arrays of the items in each list
};
}


handleAddList(s) {
  // Implement this function!
  let nameList = s;

  this.setState({ lists: this.state.lists.concat(nameList)  });
  this.setState({ items: this.state.items.[nameList] = []  });
  console.log(this.state.items);

}


handleAddItem(s) {
  // Implement this function!
  let itemName = s;

}    
/**
 * Renders the component.
 */
 render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <AddList addList={this.handleAddList.bind(this)} />
    <div id="listsDiv" className="List">
      <Lists lists={this.state.lists} items={this.state.items} addItem=
  {this.handleAddItem.bind(this)} />
    </div>
  </div>
 );
}

}

export default App;
```

Comment: Veo que tenés un error de sintaxis en `this.setState({ items: this.state.items.[nameList] = []  });`, debería ser `this.setState({ items: this.state.items[nameList] = []  });`.

Comment: Hola gracias por contestar es cierto sobraba el punto pero no me esta adicionando los arrays nuevos, sino que esta reemplazando por el nuevo cada ves que ingreso un nuevo valor

Comment: Probá si reasignando las propiedades a un nuevo objeto como `this.setState({ items: { ...this.sate.items, namelist: [] } })` te funciona.

Comment: no entiendo donde esta la funcion `setState`

Comment: por lo que estoy viendo, estas reasignando cada vez las variables `lists` e `items`, por que no simplemente haces `this.state.items[nameList] = [];` sin el `setState`

Comment: `this.setState()` es una función propia de React @LPZadkiel , por eso es que no aparece.

Comment: Kleith la reasignacion que propones no me funciona me da error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacer eso.

**1 - Simple:**

Primero crea una copia de `items` y después realizá los cambios sobre esa copia:

```
// creando copia de objeto
let items = Object.assign({}, this.state.items);
items[nameList] = [];
this.setState({ items });
```

En vez de usar `Object.assign` también podemos escribirlo así:

```
let items = {...this.state.items};
```

**2 - Usando [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)**:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  items: {
    ...prevState.items,
    [nameList]: []
  }
}))
```

Comment: Correcto ahora si esta llenando el objeto como quería Gracias Kleith